# DialogFragment onCreateView not returning custom layout view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialogfragment

I'm currently trying to use a custom layout with my DialogFragment, however it seems I'm doing something wrong. This is what my class currently looks like:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog");
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, passDataListener)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .create();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    setTitleFromBundle();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edittext, container);


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);
    tvUnits = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_units);

    setMaxCharsFromBundle();
    setTextFromBundle();
    setHintFromBundle();
    setInputTypeFromBundle();
    setUnitsTextViewFromBundle();
}
```

The positive/negative buttons show (along with the title) however, my layout does not.

Comment: If you are using dialog fragment then why using AlertDialog.Builder inOnCreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't need to override `onCreateView()`

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setRetainInstance(true);
Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog");
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edittext, null))
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, passDataListener)
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both methods `onCreateDialog` and `onCreateView` at the same time. You have to choose if you want to show a "basic dialog" then overwrite `onCreateDialog`. If you want to show a "custom dialog" then overwrite `onCreateView`. Note that you can also overwrite `onCreateDialog` and set your own layout with `youralertdialog.setView()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement only one method between `onCreateView` and `onCreateDialog`, not both of them.

- onCreateView : to supply the content of the dialog
- onCreateDialog : to create an entirely custom dialog, such as an AlertDialog, with its own content

Everything is described in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

For a complete guide you can see https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment